# Cart Items preview is visible only in catalog module

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4

I have created Cart items preview it's working fine. But it is visible only in `http://Ipaddress/magento/index.php/electronics/cell-phones.html`. If this is visible globally how Can I modified this? and flickering( when Mouseover items are visible below grid is flickering).

my code is

**magento\app\code\local\Easylife\Checkout\Block\Links.php**

```
<?php  

class Easylife_Checkout_Block_Links extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Links
{   

    public function addCartLink()
    {
        $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
        if ($parentBlock && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
            $count = $this->getSummaryQty() ? $this->getSummaryQty()
                : $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
            if ($count == 1) {
                $text = $this->__('My Cart (%s item)', $count);
            } elseif ($count > 0) {
                $text = $this->__('My Cart (%s items)', $count);
            } else {
                $text = $this->__('My Cart');
            }    

            $parentBlock->removeLinkByUrl($this->getUrl('checkout/cart'));
            $parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/cart', $text, true, array(), 50, null, 'class="top-link-cart" onMouseOver="$(\'Item_Card\').show();" ');
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\catalog.xml**

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">       
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product" name="catalog.product.cartlist" template="catalog/product/cartlist.phtml"/>               
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
```

**magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\cartlist.phtml**

```
<?php if(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount()>0) { ?>
    <div onMouseOver="$('Item_Card').show();" style="width: 500px; display:none;position: relative;left: 300px; top: -100px;" id="Item_Card">
        <div class="block block-cart" >

            <div class="block-title" onMouseOut="$('Item_Card').hide();">
                <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('My Cart') ?></span></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="block-content" onMouseOut="$('Item_Card').hide();" >
                <?php  $cartid= Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getProductIds();

            /*    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');*/ ?>
                <table class="data-table" id="wishlist-table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Product Image
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Product Details
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Price
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Edit Cart Details
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($cartid as $pid): ?>
                        <?php $pname= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);?>
                        <tr id="item_<?php echo $pid;?>">
                        <?php if($pname->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <td><a href="<?php echo $pname->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($pname, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($pname, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($pname, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a></td>
                                <td><label><p>Name : <b><?php echo $pname->getName(); ?></b></p><p>SKU : <b><?php echo $pname->getSKU(); ?></b></p><p>Description : <b><?php echo $pname->getDescription(); ?></b></p></label></td>
                                <td><label><b><?php echo number_format($pname->getPrice(),2); ?></b></label></td>
                                <td><a class="link-edit" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a></td>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                    <tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }else{?>

    <div onMouseOut="$('Item_Card').hide();" style="height: 150px;width: 200px;display:none;position: relative;left: 400px; top: -100px;" id="vinod">
        <div class="block block-cart">
            <div class="block-title">
                <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('My Cart') ?></span></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="block-content">
                <label><b><?php echo 'There is no items in your cart'; ?></b></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Can you tell me If this is visible at globally where I need to write this? and 
how can I solve flickering?

thanks.

Comment: The flickering stuff is a dublicate of this one: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15007/flickering-problem-in-magento. Again it's hard to understand what you try to explain. What do you mean with "visible at globally"?

Comment: @thebod, thanks for replying now working fine.

Comment: @MagentoNav feel free to share your answer here as it may help other developers out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have this block visible on all pages of your website then you can change the layout handle from `<catalog_category_default>` to `<default>`.

There are also a couple of other things that appear odd about your code.

1. The layout defines the block of type `catalog/product` but the block itself extends `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links`,
2. I am fairly sure that magento has most of this functionality in the system by default, well it definitely has a cart items box that could be extended to meet your needs. See `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml` - `name="cart_sidebar"`